# Why does my Bevel create nonsense at object corners?

Tags: bevel

I'm making a plastic shroud for a magnet, to use for a running bib. (This is the piece which would go on the inside of one's shirt.) It's sort of an hourglass shape, extruded in Z, with a disc removed for where the magnet will sit. So far so good!

I'd like to bevel the edges on the side of the piece which will face the wearer's skin or undergarment, and that's not going so well. The edge bevel is fine, but at the corners, I'm ending up with a lot of extra nonsense mesh I didn't anticipate.

Am I missing a switch which would give me the corner I (so obviously) intend??

Before beveling: [image: Before beveling]

After beveling, with my bevel option selections still visible: [image: After beveling]

After beveling, rotated to make the nonsense mesh more obvious: [image: Highlighting the nonsense mesh]

Comment: Firistly trying to bevel an object that shape is always going to give problems, definitely not helped by the fact that your second images shows that you've got 32 segments on it! Try reducing it to 3 maximum on that shape. Also check in Object mode that the Scale is applied (Ctrl-A > Scale) and you really need to get rid of most of the edges on that flat surface to give you any chance of success. - They'll screw up the bevelling too.

Comment: The problem is the topology, (partly arising from the Boolean). ... Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/hX9w5qo) the sort of thing you're after? By modelling instead of cutting, you can get the topo to flow with the form.